# How can I view Html pages from inside a docker container?

Tags: html, docker

I have a docker container with its own file structure. Inside it there are some html files that I am interested in viewing.
How can I view these html files correctly?

(Right now in vscode I can only see the html code)

Comment: Have you consider using a nginx or apache server?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install editor inside the container, and then you can use that editor to view your HTML source code.

Here are the commands for the same:

1. docker exec -u 0 -it <container_id> /bin/bash
2. apt-get update
3. apt-get install vim

Hope this would help.

Comment: but this will let me see the text contents, right? not the file as it is viewed by browsers...

Comment: @techStud he does not want to see the source code but the actually page

Comment: @KansaiRobot Yes, if you want to view same as that in browser then you can use the nginx image and then host your files there and map the nginx port with your machine's any port number and then you can use http://address:<port_number>/file.html

You can refer this article: https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-use-the-official-nginx-docker-image/